# Android - Good practice for button shadows

Tags: android, image, button, shadow

I'm having a hard time positioning buttons that have custom shadows.

For example, the designer created this button :

[image: image with shadow]

As you can see, the shadow is bigger at the bottom of the image.

I want the button layout to contain only the button, not the shadow around (for several reasons : alignement, effect on button etc). So I'm measuring the shadows on each side and use them as positive or negative margins. I also use android:clipChildren="false" so that the shadow can be displayed out of the button layout.

But then if I want to resize the image, all the margins are obsolete. Is it really a good practice to use images containing shadows on Android ? Or is there an easy way to achieve programmatically the shadows the designer did ?

Thanks a lot in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "standard" way to achieve a shadow would be using the elevation attribute, afaik. But i don't know if it is possible to adjust the standard shadow, generated by the elevation. Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I had to use the image above, so I couldnt use the elevation feature. I recommend using elevation as the other answers if you  have the choice.

However if like me you don't have the choice, I've managed to do it with the "clipChildren" property and negative margins. Basically I place a frameLayout in the place of the button, and add a not clipped child ImageView containing the whole image, with negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of `Elevation` functionality can came as a part of material design for android. You can define elevation for your UI elements. The higher the elevation the deeper is the shadow.

Of course there are rules and guidelines which you need to go through:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Answer (score 0):

I am agreed with *CoderP*.You should use elevation functionality.

```
     android:elevation="4dp";
```

check out some do's and don't in this Link: 
https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-object-relationships

I hope this will help you.Have a good one.